# I need help using JQuery to alert the user when a field is left empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

The provided code is fully functional, I just can not get the JQuery to provide the given alert when a field is left empty. I have already tried to add "e.preventDefault();" and it did not work. I think that my issue stems from the radio button and dropdown list, as I am not too sure how to extract their values using JQuery. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

---

```
<div class="w3-card w3-light-grey">
    <header class="w3-container w3-brown w3-text-amber w3-margin-top">
        <h1>Add A Wrestler to the Roster</h1>
    </header>

    <form action="<?php echo $phpScript; ?>" method="POST" class="w3-container">
        <p>
            <label for="fname" class="w3-text-grey">First name</label>
            <span class="w3-text-red"> *</span>
            <input id="fname" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>" class="w3-input w3-border" accesskey="F" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" required >
        </p>
    <p>
            <label for="lname" class="w3-text-grey">Last name</label>
            <span class="w3-text-red"> *</span>
            <input id="lname" value="<?php echo $lname; ?>" class="w3-input w3-border" accesskey="L" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required >
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="wins" class="w3-text-grey">Number of Wins</label>
            <span class="w3-text-red"> *</span>
            <input id="wins" value="<?php echo $wins; ?>" class="w3-input w3-border" accesskey="W" name="wins" placeholder="Wins" required >
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="losses" class="w3-text-grey">Number of Losses</label>
            <span class="w3-text-red"> *</span>
            <input id="losses" value="<?php echo $losses; ?>" class="w3-input w3-border" accesskey="S" name="losses" placeholder="Losses" required >
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="pins" class="w3-text-grey">number of Pins</label>
            <span class="w3-text-red"> *</span>
            <input id="pins" value="<?php echo $pins; ?>" class="w3-input w3-border" accesskey="P" name="pins" placeholder="Pins" required >
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Weight Class:</label>
            <span class="w3-text-red"> * <?php echo $gradeLevelError; ?></span>
            <select name="weight_class" id="weight_class">
                <option required selected disabled>Choose A Weight Class</option>
                <option value="106" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '106') ?>>106</option>
                <option value="113" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '113') ?>>113</option>
                <option value="120" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '120') ?>>120</option>
                <option value="132" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '132') ?>>132</option>
                <option value="138" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '138') ?>>138</option>
                <option value="145" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '145') ?>>145</option>
                <option value="152" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '152') ?>>152</option>
                <option value="160" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '160') ?>>160</option>
                <option value="170" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '170') ?>>170</option>
                <option value="182" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '182') ?>>182</option>
                <option value="195" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '195') ?>>195</option>
                <option value="220" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '220') ?>>220</option>
                <option value="285" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '285') ?>>285</option>

            </select> 
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Grade Level:</label>
            <span class="w3-text-red"> * <?php echo $gradeLevelError; ?></span>
            <br><input required type="radio" id="gradeLevel" name="gradeLevel" value="Fr" <?php echo radioStatus($gradeLevel, 'Fr'); ?>> Fr
            <br><input type="radio"  id="gradeLevel" name="gradeLevel" value="So" <?php echo radioStatus($gradeLevel, 'So'); ?>> So 
            <br><input type="radio"  id="gradeLevel" name="gradeLevel" value="Jr" <?php echo radioStatus($gradeLevel, 'Jr'); ?>> Jr
            <br><input type="radio"  id="gradeLevel" name="gradeLevel" value="Sr" <?php echo radioStatus($gradeLevel, 'Sr'); ?>> Sr 
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Wrestling Level:</label>
            <span class="w3-text-red"> * <?php echo $wrestlingLevelError; ?></span>
            <br><input required type="radio" id="wrestlingLevel" name="wrestlingLevel" value="JV" <?php echo radioStatus($wrestlingLevel, 'jv'); ?>> Jv
            <br><input type="radio" id="wrestlingLevel" name="wrestlingLevel" value="V" <?php echo radioStatus($wrestlingLevel, 'V'); ?>> V
        </p>
    <p>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" id="sub" class="w3-btn w3-brown w3-text-amber">Save</button>
            <span class="w3-text-red"><?php echo $formError; ?></span>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
<?php include 'inc.footer.php'; ?>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sub').click(function(e) {

        var first = $('#fname').val();
        var last = $('#lname').val();
        var wins = $('#wins').val();
        var losses = $('#losses').val();
        var pins = $('#pins').val();
        var weight_class = $('#weight_class option:selected').val();
        var gradeLevel= $("input[name='gradeLevel']:checked").val();
        var wrestlingLevel  = $("input[name='wrestlingLevel']:checked").val();

        first.trim();
        last.trim();
        weight_class.trim();
        losses.trim();
        pins.trim();
        gradeLevel.trim();
        wrestlingLevel.trim();
        weight_class.trim();

        alert(f);

        if (weight_class == '' || first == '' || last == '' || wins == '' || losses == '' || pins == '' || gradeLevel == '' || wrestlingLevel == '') {
            alert('Empty fields not allowed');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If you are using html 5, you can use input's 'pattern' attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about the radio and select elements. `.val()` is not what you are looking for, rather your can count the length of checked items.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sub').click(function(e) {

    var first = $('#fname').val();
    var last = $('#lname').val();
    var wins = $('#wins').val();
    var losses = $('#losses').val();
    var pins = $('#pins').val();

    // remove val() from the following
    // Add :not(:first-child) to eliminate "Choose A Weight Class"
    var weight_class = $('#weight_class option:not(:first-child):selected');
    var gradeLevel = $("input[name='gradeLevel']:checked");
    var wrestlingLevel = $("input[name='wrestlingLevel']:checked");

    first = first.trim();
    last = last.trim();
    // no need for trim() for checkboxes and radio
    //  weight_class.trim();
    losses = losses.trim();
    pins = pins.trim();
    //gradeLevel.trim();
    //  wrestlingLevel.trim();
    // weight_class.trim();
    //  alert(f);

    if (first == '' || last == '' || wins == '' || losses == '' || pins == '' || weight_class.length == 0 || gradeLevel.length == 0 || wrestlingLevel.length == 0) {
      alert('Empty fields not allowed');
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w3-card w3-light-grey">
  <header class="w3-container w3-brown w3-text-amber w3-margin-top">
    <h1>Add A Wrestler to the Roster</h1>
  </header>

  <form action="<?php echo $phpScript; ?>" method="POST" class="w3-container">
    <p>
      <label for="fname" class="w3-text-grey">First name</label>
      <span class="w3-text-red"> *</span>
      <input id="fname" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>" class="w3-input w3-border" accesskey="F" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="lname" class="w3-text-grey">Last name</label>
      <span class="w3-text-red"> *</span>
      <input id="lname" value="<?php echo $lname; ?>" class="w3-input w3-border" accesskey="L" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="wins" class="w3-text-grey">Number of Wins</label>
      <span class="w3-text-red"> *</span>
      <input id="wins" value="<?php echo $wins; ?>" class="w3-input w3-border" accesskey="W" name="wins" placeholder="Wins" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="losses" class="w3-text-grey">Number of Losses</label>
      <span class="w3-text-red"> *</span>
      <input id="losses" value="<?php echo $losses; ?>" class="w3-input w3-border" accesskey="S" name="losses" placeholder="Losses" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="pins" class="w3-text-grey">number of Pins</label>
      <span class="w3-text-red"> *</span>
      <input id="pins" value="<?php echo $pins; ?>" class="w3-input w3-border" accesskey="P" name="pins" placeholder="Pins" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Weight Class:</label>
      <span class="w3-text-red"> * <?php echo $gradeLevelError; ?></span>
      <select name="weight_class" id="weight_class">
        <option required selected disabled>Choose A Weight Class</option>
        <option value="106" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '106') ?>>106</option>
        <option value="113" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '113') ?>>113</option>
        <option value="120" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '120') ?>>120</option>
        <option value="132" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '132') ?>>132</option>
        <option value="138" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '138') ?>>138</option>
        <option value="145" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '145') ?>>145</option>
        <option value="152" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '152') ?>>152</option>
        <option value="160" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '160') ?>>160</option>
        <option value="170" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '170') ?>>170</option>
        <option value="182" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '182') ?>>182</option>
        <option value="195" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '195') ?>>195</option>
        <option value="220" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '220') ?>>220</option>
        <option value="285" <?php echo selectedStatus($weight_class, '285') ?>>285</option>

      </select>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Grade Level:</label>
      <span class="w3-text-red"> * <?php echo $gradeLevelError; ?></span>
      <br><input required type="radio" id="gradeLevel" name="gradeLevel" value="Fr" <?php echo radioStatus($gradeLevel, 'Fr'); ?>> Fr
      <br><input type="radio" id="gradeLevel" name="gradeLevel" value="So" <?php echo radioStatus($gradeLevel, 'So'); ?>> So
      <br><input type="radio" id="gradeLevel" name="gradeLevel" value="Jr" <?php echo radioStatus($gradeLevel, 'Jr'); ?>> Jr
      <br><input type="radio" id="gradeLevel" name="gradeLevel" value="Sr" <?php echo radioStatus($gradeLevel, 'Sr'); ?>> Sr
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Wrestling Level:</label>
      <span class="w3-text-red"> * <?php echo $wrestlingLevelError; ?></span>
      <br><input required type="radio" id="wrestlingLevel" name="wrestlingLevel" value="JV" <?php echo radioStatus($wrestlingLevel, 'jv'); ?>> Jv
      <br><input type="radio" id="wrestlingLevel" name="wrestlingLevel" value="V" <?php echo radioStatus($wrestlingLevel, 'V'); ?>> V
    </p>
    <p>
      <button type="submit" name="submit" id="sub" class="w3-btn w3-brown w3-text-amber">Save</button>
      <span class="w3-text-red"><?php echo $formError; ?></span>
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: still not working, unfortunately. My second guess was my <script> tags.

Comment: I checked and it is working fine. I updated my answer with a runnable example.

Comment: It is working now, I have this same JQuery function for two other web pages, create account and log in, they both were fine using "            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>" . I am just curiout as to what made this function different to where it had to use a differenet script link?

Comment: The link your provided supplies an old (very old) jQuery version "1.10.2". The one I used was "3.3.1"

Comment: That makes sense, I got it from an older question on here. Anyways, thanks a ton I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

`Trim();` creates a new String

So This:

```
    first.trim();
    last.trim();
    weight_class.trim();
    losses.trim();
    pins.trim();
    gradeLevel.trim();
    wrestlingLevel.trim();
    weight_class.trim();
```

Should be

```
    first = first.trim();
    last = last.trim();
    weight_class = weight_class.trim();
    losses = losses.trim();
    pins = pins.trim();
    gradeLevel = gradeLevel.trim();
    wrestlingLevel = wrestlingLevel.trim();
    weight_class = weight_class.trim();
```

Comment: I changed it and it still does not work how I need it to.